# Tensorflow Lite: How to check input_layer_shape and input_layer_type for converting pb to tflite

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, toco

How to fill in the correct parameters for converting tflite?

Here is the failed message and pb info as below,

**(1) failed message**

```
~/tensorflow/pkg/tensorflow$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/toco \
--input_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF \
--input_file='retrained_graph.pb' \
--output_format=TFLITE \
--output_file='retrained_graph.tflite' \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--inference_input_type=FLOAT \
--output_arrays=final_result \
--input_arrays=batch_size,phase_train \
--input_shapes=1,160,160,3:False \
--mean_values=128 \
--std_values=128
2018-09-06 17:16:14.249938: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/model_cmdline_flags.cc:263] Check failed: mean_values.size() == model_flags->input_arrays_size()
```

**(2) pb info**

```
xxxx:~/tensorflow/pkg/tensorflow$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/summarize_graph --in_graph='zzz/retrained_graph.pb'
Found 2 possible inputs: (name=batch_size, type=int32(3), shape=<unknown>) (name=phase_train, type=bool(10), shape=<unknown>) 
No variables spotted.
Found 1 possible outputs: (name=final_result, op=Softmax) 
Found 23514555 (23.51M) const parameters, 0 (0) variable parameters, and 675 control_edges
Op types used: 2019 Switch, 1104 Const, 1057 Identity, 449 Sub, 449 Merge, 247 Mul, 224 FusedBatchNorm, 132 Conv2D, 131 Relu, 24 Add, 23 ConcatV2, 21 BiasAdd, 3 MaxPool, 3 Shape, 3 Reshape, 2 MatMul, 2 Placeholder, 1 PlaceholderWithDefault, 1 AvgPool, 1 StridedSlice, 1 Softmax, 1 RealDiv, 1 RandomUniform, 1 QueueDequeueUpToV2, 1 FIFOQueueV2, 1 Pack, 1 Floor
To use with tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model try these arguments:
bazel run tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model -- --graph=zzz/retrained_graph.pb --show_flops --input_layer=batch_size,phase_train --input_layer_type=int32,bool --input_layer_shape=: --output_layer=final_result
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using quantization with your model, you can skip the `--mean_values` and `--std_values` input args entirely.

Those flags are only necessary when using quantization (`--inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8`). If you do use quantization and specify the `mean` and `std`, you're required to do so for each input (in this case, both `batch_size` and `phase_train`).

Comment: Here is my question, It cannot pass False. How can I do my next step?
2018-09-10 16:19:51.880193: F tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/model_cmdline_flags.cc:327] Check failed: absl::SimpleAtoi(dim_str, &size) Failed to parse input_shape: False
已經終止 (核心已傾印)

Comment: `False` is not a shape. What kind of tensor is phase_train?

Comment: I choose the FaceNet model to train the own model.
(1)the own model info:
batch_size==>Placeholder
batch_size==>Placeholder
phase_train==>Placeholder
phase_train==>Placeholder
batch_join/fifo_queue==>FIFOQueueV2
batch_join==>QueueDequeueUpToV2e
input==>Identity

Comment: (2)the part of the training script: 
images_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
embeddings = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("embeddings:0")
phase_train_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("phase_train:0")
embedding_size = embeddings.get_shape()[1]
feed_dict = {images_placeholder:resized_input_values, phase_train_placeholder:False} 
bottleneck_values = sess.run(embeddings, feed_dict=feed_dict)